# Load angularjs controller dynamically from html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 2 controllers.
I get a composite JS object which has some elements+JS objects+numerous arrays from the first controller

I want to initialize the 2nd controller multiple times with various array objects respectively.

I am using this code to iniatialize the 2nd controller.

```
app.controller('SSController', function($scope) {
$scope.init = function(initData)
{
    $scope.initData = initData;     
};

<div ng-controller="TTController">
    <div ng-controller="SSController" ng-init='init({currData})'>
    </div>
</div>
```

where currData is a property of the scope object of TTController.

If I pass a hardcoded number in the init, it gets passed, but not the currData object. Even an integer value which comes from currData, such as currData.id is not getting passed.

Any ideas how this is done ?

Comment: Why not just use the parent controller? Why make a child controller?

Comment: Basically I am trying to iterate the array elements on the UI on clicking back and next buttons. The child controller will take up the specific array passed from html and iterate over it when the back or next buttons are clicked. Now I want the same controller to be able to process different arrays when passed

Comment: you are talking about behavior; so I think what you are looking for is a directive not a controller. Please consider writing a directive to handle the child scope rather than using a child controller. I think you will have better luck and also be more angular.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be writing a directive and not a controller. Please consider the following pattern.

```
<div ng-controller="TTController">
    <div my-process-array="dataToWatch">
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
app.directive('myProcessArray', function(){
    return function(scope, elem, attrs){
         elem.bind('click', function(){
             // do click stuff 
         });

         scope.$watch(attrs.myProcessArray, function(newdata, olddata){
               // do stuff with data from the parent controller.
          });
    };       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, define some service which holds the data; Initially,inject the service in to the TTController and then modify/fill in the data and then inject the same service into the SSController.. :) Use of Services is better compared to directives and controllers.. And by the way services are the better means to serve the data.. :)